# Install4j: extending AbstractInstallAction class to another abstract class and implementing that instead

Tags: java, install4j

For my application requirement, I need all my action classes to do a few things every time it performs an action. I have created a new abstract class that extends the `AbstractInstallAction` class like the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractInvestigatorInstallAction extends AbstractInstallAction {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7004320241363920697L;

@Override
public boolean install(InstallerContext context) throws UserCanceledException {
    ActionReport report = investigate(context);
    return onFinish(context, report);
}

public abstract ActionReport investigate(Context context);

public abstract boolean onFinish(Context context, ActionReport report);
}
```

Now, suppose I have created a custom action class `BlaInvestigation` which extends this `AbstractInvestigatorInstallAction` instead of the `AbstractInstallAction`. But when I add both the classes in the Install4j Project, I don't see the new action class `BlaInvestigation` when I look for the custom action from the `search action in custom code`, I don't find it. Should I directly implement the `InstallAction` class instead? Does creating a local AbstractInstallAction work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 7.0, the custom code search dialog does not check the class hierarchy. If you add an additional `implements InstallAction` to all derived class, the dialog will find them.